# iOS equivalent to layered div's in HTML/CSS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, ios7

I'm porting a PhoneGap application to native iOS targeting iOS 7. One of the elements is a rectangular `<div>` with another `<div>` layered on top that has a variable height and produces a meter effect. The best visual I can think of is a thermometer.

Is there a recommended UI element that would simulate this in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

`UIView` is the closest thing to a general `div` in HTML.  If you override its `drawRect:` method, you can perform whatever drawing code you'd like using [`NSGraphicsContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSGraphicsContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (including just painting the background a certain color).  If you want something more elaborate, you can use a `UIImageView` and display an image for the various parts of your control.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods.org has a lot of great reusable iOS components. One that sounds like it may meet your needs is MSSimpleGauge:

https://github.com/sabymike/MSSimpleGauge

[image: Taken from the github page readme]